# New overlay won't stay when mouseX and mouseY coordinates match constraints - Processing 3

Tags: java, processing

```
  void draw() {

  boolean onTheMoon = false;
  drawGrid(); // Old overlay animation. 
  if ((mouseX > 50) && (mouseX < 150) && (mouseY > 50) && (mouseY < 150)) {
    onTheMoon = true;
  } 
  if (onTheMoon) 
  {
    do 
    {
      moonLanding(); // New overlay method 
    } 
    while ((mouseX > 800) && (mouseX < 1000) && (mouseY > 400) && (mouseY < 700)); //Coordinates for new location on overlay
    }
  rocketShip(); // Calling my rocketship method. Rocket made of shapes using mouseX and mouseY
}
```

Hi everyone, I am trying to keep an overlay running once the mouseX and mouseY coordinates match the conditions of the top if statement in the code above. The problem I am facing now is when the mouseX and mouseY move away from the area the old overlay appears and it is ruining the animation. I am testing out different methods but nothing is working. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The `do/while` part looks suspicious. Remember you're calling this in `draw()` so `rocketShip()` won't be called (and rendering can't continue) until the while loop completes execution. What should happen when the mouse is within 50,150 bounding box ?

Comment: Hi George, When the mouse hits the 50,150 boundary a black background appears with a circle shape in the lower right. I want the overlay to stay present until the mouseX and mouseY coordinates reach the new condition (which is the circle shape in the lower right)

Comment: If I were to remove the do/while what other technique could I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments above it sounds like an `if` condition will do the job and there's no need for the `do/while` loop.

You have this boolean expression: `(mouseX > 800) && (mouseX < 1000) && (mouseY > 400) && (mouseY < 700)`.

You want `moonLanding()` to be called only when this condition is [not(`!`)](https://processing.org/reference/logicalNOT.html) met:

```
 void draw() {

  boolean onTheMoon = false;
  drawGrid(); // Old overlay animation. 
  if ((mouseX > 50) && (mouseX < 150) && (mouseY > 50) && (mouseY < 150)) {
    onTheMoon = true;
  } 
  if (onTheMoon) 
  {
    if (!((mouseX > 800) && (mouseX < 1000) && (mouseY > 400) && (mouseY < 700))){
      moonLanding(); // New overlay method 
    }
  rocketShip(); // Calling my rocketship method. Rocket made of shapes using mouseX and mouseY
}
```

this is equivalent to:

```
 if (((mouseX > 800) && (mouseX < 1000) && (mouseY > 400) && (mouseY < 700)) == false){
          moonLanding(); // New overlay method 
        }
```

One suggestion I have, if your program will require more mouse/bounding conditions is to encapsulate the conditions in a re-usable function.

for example:

```
 void draw() {

  boolean onTheMoon = false;
  drawGrid(); // Old overlay animation. 
  if (isMouseOverTopLeft()) {
    onTheMoon = true;
  } 
  if (onTheMoon) 
  {
    if (!isMouseOverBottomRight()){
      moonLanding(); // New overlay method 
    }
  rocketShip(); // Calling my rocketship method. Rocket made of shapes using mouseX and mouseY
}

boolean isMouseOverTopLeft(){
  return isMouseOverRect(50, 50, 150, 150);
}

boolean isMouseOverBottomRight(){
  return isMouseOverRect(800, 400, 1000, 700);
}

boolean isMouseOverRect(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2){
  return (mouseX >= x1 && mouseX <= x2) && (mouseY >= y1 && mouseY <= y2);
}
```

I can easily see getting ridiculous with many isOverX methods, but by then you could start storing making a data structure to hold bounds an a list of bounds, etc.
The idea is to make the code easier to read.

Comment: Hi George, this was extremely helpful. The second alternative is the best method but I would still like to get the first solution working. It seems the first solution still doesn't work as once the mouse coordinates are moved from the((mouseX > 50) && (mouseX < 150) && (mouseY > 50) && (mouseY < 150)) it looks like the boolean is going false. This is causing the old overlay to appear immediately again once the conditions aren't met.

Comment: I don't have enough context over what the overall behaviour of the sketch should be. The above indeed, does what it says: displays moonLandinding if the top left has been hovered and the mouse hasn't reached the top right corner. There are multiple ways to hide the overlay and keep it hidden. One options is to use the `onTheMoon` variable: you can add an `else` clause to the `if(!isMouseOverBottomRight())` condition in which you reset `onTheMoon` back to `false`. `moonLanding()` shouldn't be called until you hover over top left again, however `rocketShip()` will also not be called...

Comment: if you want to still run `rocketShip()` and not call `moonLanding()` you will need an extra boolean variable so you can toggle calling `moonLanding()` independent of the other conditions. Hope this makes sense